# Function declarators in C

Tags: c

§6.7.6.3 Function declarators

> 2) The only storage-class specifier that shall occur in a parameter declaration is register.

§6.7.6.3 Function declarators

> 13) The storage-class specifier in the declaration specifiers for a parameter declaration, if present, is ignored unless the declared parameter is one of the members of the parameter type list for a function definition.

I have declared and defined like this...

```
int function(static int param)
{
    return param;
}
```

Visual Studio is throwing a warning. What I understood is, if we use `register` as a parameter type in the declaration of a function, it should compile without warning. Other than `register`, it will ignore the storage class and throw a warning message to user. 
Is my understanding proper?

Thanks

Comment: Can you include the warning that Visual Studio is giving you?

Comment: Does `register` even make a difference in modern compilers?

Comment: @druciferre: warning C4042: 'param' : has bad storage class

Answer (score 7):

I believe 6.7.6.3 is saying that storage-class specifiers are ignored in function **declarations**; it says that it's ignored unless the parameter is part of the parameter type list for a function **definition**. Since you're showing a function *definition*, it would not be proper for the compiler to ignore this invalid storage-class specifier here.

Comment: standard is saying that storage-class specifiers are ignored in function declarations..
So i tried  with the declaration "void mp(auto int);". But I am getting error .

error :-  error: storage class specified for unnamed parameter.

can you tell me please why am i having the error in the function declarations (since storage-class specifiers are ignored in function declarations, so it shouldn't raise an error;)?

Answer (score 1):

First of all the compiler that you get with `Visual Studio` is not according to `c99/c11` standard.

The function `definition` should not allow the use of storage class specifiers other than `register`. It should flag it as a bad use of storage class. As stated, VS compiler is not according to standard, it is throwing a warning message.

Answer (score 1):

AS said Visual Studio is not according to c99/c11 standard.
that is why this is throwing as warning. if you compile with gcc ..

you will get `error: storage class specified for parameter âparamâ` at the place of declaration of function and defination of the function

You can use only register should not other ones Like static, extern